# BigQuery gives "Response too large" for COUNT(*) over small tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset with the following 7 daily summary tables, each of which is small:

```
summary_broad_20130104_hourly         199 k rows    8395 KB
summary_broad_20130105_hourly         198 k rows    8347 KB
summary_broad_20130106_hourly         197 k rows    8319 KB
summary_broad_20130107_hourly         194 k rows    8190 KB
summary_broad_20130108_hourly         197 k rows    8338 KB
summary_broad_20130109_hourly         201 k rows    8490 KB
summary_broad_20130110_hourly         202 k rows    8534 KB
```

I get "Response too large" when doing a simple `select count(*)` over all of these tables (04-10):

```
$ bq query "select count(*) from summary_broad_20130104_hourly,summary_broad_20130105_hourly,summary_broad_20130106_hourly,summary_broad_20130107_hourly,summary_broad_20130108_hourly,summary_broad_20130109_hourly,summary_broad_20130110_hourly"
BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job '987928363675:job_bb504ce6ea31416db3f8762d3c244d93': Response too large to return.
```

However, I get a successful response if I restrict the query to tables 04-06:

```
$ bq query "select count(*) from summary_broad_20130104_hourly,summary_broad_20130105_hourly,summary_broad_20130106_hourly"
+--------+
|  f0_   |
+--------+
| 594721 |
+--------+
```

But if I extend to tables 04-07 then I can repro the error again:

```
$ bq query "select count(*) from summary_broad_20130104_hourly,summary_broad_20130105_hourly,summary_broad_20130106_hourly,summary_broad_20130107_hourly"
BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job '987928363675:job_22ea222b4b0549a98bb9e90f1a2ac539': Response too large to return.
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? The queried data is small (~40MB in the 04-07 case), and I expect that the `select count(*)` is a node-local aggregation with a negligible amount of intermediate data.

Comment: Since you have no join condition, it's trying to construct the cross-product of 7 tables, whose size is the product of all their sizes. That's on the order of 10^37 rows.

Comment: The answer in your second query seems wrong. `199k * 198k * 197k` is close to `8*10^15`.

Comment: Actually, bigquery changes the meaning of `,` from `join` to `union`, which is why the `count(*)` is additive and not multiplicative. Search for "union" in the [bigquery docs](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#from).

Comment: Probably a bug. Wait for google engineer's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is, in fact, a bug. We're investigating it, can repro it locally, and hope to have a fix soon.

Comment: By the way, if it's feasible, a short-term workaround is to export and re-import the tables.